# When to use temporary registers vs saved registers?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

Whenever I pass arguments (`$a0` or `$a1`) to a section (label) I reach using `jal`, does it matter if I use temporary registers (like `$t0`) instead of saved registers like (`$s0`) to hold or manipulate the arguments in that section?
Is there any risk using one set instead of the other while the section is running?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by segment?

Comment: @markgz updated to section. Something along the lines of a helper function which will eventually return to the main caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "segment" you mean *function call*, you should follow the MIPS calling convention described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#MIPS).  A function can change the values of $t0,...,$t9 without needing to restore them before returning. Code that calls a function must assume that $t0,...,$t9 values have been changed when the function returns.

Comment: But there won't be any instance of concurrency while the callee is running, correct?

Comment: Unless you are running on a MIPS CPU, like the 34k family, that supports hardware multi-threading, there is no concurrency between a function and its caller.

Answer (score 1):

if you are implementing a function call from somewhere that supports the calling convention (a C program calling your asm code).  No you dont HAVE to make all of your own internal calls conform so long as those internal callees are assumed to not be visible outside that context.  Meaning you cannot call them from C for example because you are choosing not to conform to the C calling convention for that compiler and target.  So long as the entry point that you will be calling from the outside, from the outside conforms to the standard then you can do whatever you want.

The pros and cons are things like not conforming can improve performance, but conforming makes register management and maintenance easier.